# ytmusicapi: JSON is not serializable in ytmusic.search

Tags: python, json, youtube-api

I am using ytmusicapi in my project. Here's my code.

```py
from ytmusicapi import YTMusic
ytmusic = YTMusic()
rawdata = ytmusic.search(query,filter='songs') #error still will occurs without filters
```

But I met this error:

```py
Object of type Message is not JSON serializable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\dispatcher.py", line 222, in handler_worker
    await handler.callback(self.client, *args)
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\pyromod\listen\listen.py", line 93, in resolve_listener
    await self.user_callback(client, message, *args)
  File "d:\Desktop\coding\telegram\main.py", line 84, in start_command
    rawdata = ytmusic.search(query,filter='songs')
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\ytmusicapi\mixins\browsing.py", line 145, in search
    response = self._send_request(endpoint, body)
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\ytmusicapi\ytmusic.py", line 133, in _send_request
    response = self._session.post(YTM_BASE_API + endpoint + YTM_PARAMS + additionalParams,
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 577, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 515, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 443, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 321, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 473, in prepare_body
    body = complexjson.dumps(json, allow_nan=False)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Message is not JSON serializable
```

How can I fix it? I had search for articles in the web to solve `JSON is not serializable` but not works for this case.

Any suggestion or advice would help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sry, this is a bit unrelated but, do you happen to know how to add multiple filters. like what if I want `ytmusic.search(query,filter='songs')` and `ytmusic.search(query,filter='videos')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by updating the module with `pip`